# Multiple Checkboxes search using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any script or code for multiple check boxes using Ajax j-query. ? i need this type of code very urgent.. i have done this through submit button but now i need using Ajax.. i have use multiple check un-check boxes

```
   function checkUncheckAll(theElement) {
var theForm = theElement.form, z = 0;
for(z=0; z<theForm.length;z++){
    if(theForm[z].type == 'checkbox' && theForm[z].name != 'checkall'){
        theForm[z].checked = theElement.checked;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see any ajax codes here

Comment: I need ajax code or any script for this solution

Answer (score 0):

TRy this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/Udr3W/1/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" onclick="checktoggle(this)" />

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check5" />

function checktoggle(obj) {
   // alert($(obj).prop("checked"));
 $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",$(obj).prop("checked"));   
}
```